# Increment variable without initializing

Tags: python, python-2.7, chimera

I'm extracting a bunch of features from a protein (using a scientific software called UCSF Chimera, which only works with Python 2.7).

I have a function that returns a `NamedTuple` with the results from a ton of counters--around 35 of them (where each counter represents some sort of sum of features).

At first, I wrote something like this:

```
var1, var2, var3, ... var35 = (0, ) * 35

for my_object in my_objects:
     var1 += my_object.getVar1()
     # etc
     return MyFeatures(var1 = var1, var2 = var2, ...)
```

This looks pretty messy, in part because `var1, var2, .... = (0, ) * 35` takes up quite a few lines.

I'm thinking about rewriting the code like this:

```
for my_object in my_objects:
    var1 = var1+my_object.getVar1() if 'var1' in vars() else my_object.getVar1()
    # etc
    return MyFeatures(var1 = var1, var2 = var2, ...)
```

But repeating that 35 times might be even worse than the initialization block in the previous version.

Do you have any suggestions? Is there some sort of best practice for initializing a large group of counters--is there a pythonic way to increment a variable that isn't yet initialized?

Comment: Why don't you use a list or dict of counters?

Comment: Having a bunch of variables names differing only in a number is NEVER the right answer.  You want a list: `vars = [0] * 35` - and increment the elements of that list: `vars[whatever] += 1`.

Comment: @jasonharper -- I should clarify, the actual names are *not* `var1`, `var2`, etc. They are things like "aaind_molecular_volume_sum", "oh_rxn_constant_sum", etc.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille That may be the way to go. The reason I held out on that initially was because of the return statement: `return myFeatures(var1 = my_values['var1'])` seemed verbose/messy for 35 items. But, thinking about it now--it might just be that I don't need to use a NamedTuple and can just return the `my_values` dictionary.
The nice thing about the NamedTuple is that it ensures that my return value has the features that I'd expect, but I can do that afterwards with unit tests instead.

Comment: What does it mean to increment an uninitialized variable?  `a  = b + c` will work only if `b` and `c` are defined, but you have one of them with no value.

Comment: How about partial evaluation and currying ? https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/curry.html

Comment: @Prune `a += 1` only works if `a` is previously defined. So, by 'increment an uninitialized variable', I mean an `a += 1` statement that doesn't require `a` be previously defined.

Comment: Right -- I'm asking you to explain the semantic contradiction.  This is equivalent to `a = a + 1`; your RHS `a` is the `b` of my more general operation.  If `a` is undefined, what do you expect from `a+1`, and why?

Comment: @Prune Ahh, that makes sense. I would like `a` to have a default value of 0, like with `defaultdict`, since `a` represents a counter. I would prefer that `a` be an actual variable, instead of a dictionary key, but (as Thierry pointed out), a dictionary should technically work.

Comment: Yes.  I provided the canonical duplicate, which includes Thierry's answer.  By definition, Python variables do *not* have default values, particularly to avoid the myriad debugging situations most of us have suffered.  If you want a default value, then you need to use something that specifically provides it as an override to the Python default -- such as `defaultdict`.

Comment: When you're trying to deal with a collection of values in a common way, most languages expect you to use a standard agglomeration data structure.  Python provides various degrees of that.  Your `vars` implementation with an appropriate loop would do ... but, again, you need to *somewhere* define the set of desired variable names you want in the `for ... in` iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put all your counters in a dict, and initialize them with the `dict.fromkeys` method:

```
var_names = ["aaind_molecular_volume_sum", "oh_rxn_constant_sum"]
counters = dict.fromkeys(var_names, 0)
print(counters)
# {'aaind_molecular_volume_sum': 0, 'oh_rxn_constant_sum': 0}

counters["oh_rxn_constant_sum"] += 1
print(counters)
# {'aaind_molecular_volume_sum': 0, 'oh_rxn_constant_sum': 1}
```